# Replacing 18650 batteries for AA batteries

Tags: batteries

I bought a robot that requires batteries. I did not realize it needed two 18650 batteries. In the docs it says it requires at least 7.2V. How can I use AA batteries to power it? I am thinking 5 batteries would suffice but I am not sure there are battery cases for 5 AAs 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Check the maximum allowed voltage. If you use AA batteries, you'll need 5-6 of them. I don't know of any cases for 5, but 2 and 3 and 4 exist. So you could combine them. Keep in mind that alkaline batteries cannot compete with the energy density (mass or volume) of 18650's. And so they will not last as long, almost assuredly. Also, you need to find out what the required current is. The AA batteries have a significant limit to them that is very much lower than the 18650's. So this might be yet another problem ahead. Tell us what the doc says about required current compliances.

Comment: Data point: 2 x 18650s will go from about 8.4V to 6V during discharge. 4 x A Alkaline will go from about 8.2V to 5V during discharge, so voltage range is similar. A top AA Alkaine has ABOUT 4 Wh energy. A 3 Ah 18650 LiIon has about 11 Wh energy.
So 2 x 18650 LiIon = 22+ Wh and 5 x AA ~~= 20 Wh - so they are reasonably comparable. However, as others have noted, current capability from AA Alkalines will usually be lower.

Answer (score 1):

Data point: 2 x 18650s will go from about 8.4V to 6V during discharge.
4 x AA Alkaline will go from about 8.2V to 5V during discharge, so voltage range is similar.

A top AA Alkaline has ABOUT 4 Wh energy - depending on discharge rate. Some cells have full data sheets available.
A 3 Ah 18650 LiIon has about 11 Wh energy.

So 2 x 18650 LiIon = 22+ Wh and 5 x AA ~~= 20 Wh - so they are reasonably comparable.

However, as others have noted, current capability from AA Alkalines will usually be lower.

If you can manage to use 2 x 18650s it will be 'more satisfactory'.
There is a very small chance that the Robot. uses a split supply (+/- battery relative to ground) - in which case you cannot use an odd number of replacement cells. [As they specified Vbat needing to be >- 7.2V the split battery idea is unlikely]